# Wordpress for Podcast Network

Tags: categories, podcasting

Is there a theme or some hack of the categories system that I can use to create a site for a podcast network? I want it similar to [This Week in Tech](http://twit.tv) in that all the podcasts will appear on the front page, but also each have their own homepage.

I do not think a multi-site installation will be my solution. Each podcast must have its own RSS feed with podcast enclosures.

Any ideas on how this could be done? I'm thinking that each podcast would be a category and each podcast home would be a separate category listing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Theme will do, for the most part.

Simply install the [Blubrry PowerPress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/powerpress/) or the [podPress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/podpress/), and away you go!

Comment: I think PowerPress is the way to go currently; podPress hasn't been updated in some time

Answer (score 2):

I am the lead developer of the [Blubrry PowerPress](http://create.blubrry.com/resources/powerpress/) plugin.

As of this writing, there are 5 ways to approach this, each dependent on your goals.

If each podcast can have the same branding (aka web site theme and domain name), then the following are all excellent options available in PowerPress...

- Category Podcasting - extend WordPress categories to include podcasting
- Podcast Channels - Provides podcast only feeds, allows you to write one post but have 2 or more formats/recordings to 1 blog post separated by feed.
- Post Type Podcasting - As titled, allows you to create post type specific podcast only feeds
- Taxonomy Podcasting - Allows for taxonomies (such as tags, or custom taxonomies) to include podcasting

Even though you said you do not want to use MultiSite, PowerPress does work with MultiSite and there is now a [Blubrry PowerPress MultiSite](http://create.blubrry.com/resources/powerpress/powerpress-multisite-addon/) add-on plugin that adds MultiSite specific features. PowerPress with MultiSite is the best option if you want each podcast to have it's own domain and/or unique theme and branding.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) are your friend. Just make a post type for each podcast and then post the episodes to that post type.

It appears there are also many plugins that my come in handy. I did a quick [search for PodCast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=podcast) and got several promising results.

As far as themes. The possibilities are pretty much endless you can [buy a pro theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/commercial/), [modify an existing theme](http://themehybrid.com/archives/2009/01/skeleton-wordpress-theme), or [start from scratch](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

There are many routes to go and many solutions. As it stands you're question is too open ended for me to give you an exact direction to go.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to just use categories to divvy up your podcasts?

If so, then check out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/powerpress/

Its the plugin i ise for podcasts, it allows category casting, essentiall individual feeds per category assigned

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing right now and I went the MU route. The custom post type method would work well if you are not planing on having multiple users managing their own shows, or are looking for a lot of content outside of individual episode postings.